# Lower and upper sums are equal.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function such that the lower (and upper) sums are all equal. Show that $f$ is constant.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What are upper and lower sums? Do you mean Darboux sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given partition $P$ I will denote the lower sum by $L(f, P)$ and the upper sum by $U(f, P)$.

Suppose $f$ is not constant. Choose $c_1, c_2 \in [a, b]$ so that $f(c_1) \neq f(c_2)$. Without loss of generality, suppose $f(c_1) < f(c_2)$, and that $c_1 < c_2$. Consider the "trvial" partition. i.e. $P = \{a, b\}$. Now:
\begin{align*}
L(f, P) &= \sum_{i}\min\{f(x):x\in[x_i,x_{i+1}]\}(x_{i+1}-x_i)\\
&= \min\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}(b-a)\\
&≤ f(c_1)(b-a)\\
&< f(c_2)(b-a)\\
&≤ \max\{f(x):x\in[a,b]\}(b-a)\\
&= U(f,P)
\end{align*}
Thus if $f$ is nonconstant, the upper and lower sums are not all equal. Hence if the upper and lower sums are all equal, $f$ is constant as required.